# ASIHTTPRequest adding headers to the request

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest

I am using ASIHTTPRequest, and i have to make use of the POST method to send some values to the server. So, for this i have to set headers and its corresponding values.

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Referer" value:@"http://allseeing-i.com/"];
```

The following are headers that is needed to be included in my application, and how could i include the once with Semi-Colons (`"Content-Type" = "text/html";` , `"Keep-Alive" = "timeout=15, max=100";` etc)

```
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";

    Date = "Wed, 21 Jun 2011 09:09:57 GMT";

    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=15, max=100";

    Server = Apache;

    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `addRequestHeader` in the same way as you're setting Referer. You don't need to include those semicolons - I think the ; are only there as an artifact of the method used to capture the headers. You do not use `;` like that in HTTP.

eg:

```
[request addRequestHeader:@"Keep-Alive" value:@"timeout=15, max=100"];
```

Comment: Ok, but do i have to use the double quotes `""` ? ex : `"Keep-Alive" = "timeout=15, max=100";` <-- see the double quotes

Comment: I'd added an example to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add `[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];`

Comment: But i still have to add the headers right ? So do i have to use the double quotes "" while setting the headers to the request ?